# My while is only returning the first result

Tags: c#, database, while-loop

I'm using a while to try to show all the rows in the database table that contain the card number equal to the one entered, it's not working, it's just reading the first line.

```
private static string getExtrato(string query)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAD-PC-023\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=bank;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = query })
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read() == true)
            {
                    if (reader.GetString(1) == null)
                    {
                        return "\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " levantou: " + reader.GetString(2) + " euros " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " depositou: " + reader.GetString(1) + " euros " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3);
                    }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}

private static string extratoOperacao(string numeroCartao)
{
    return getExtrato($@"SELECT CardNumber, Deposit, Withdraw, DataHora FROM MoveInfo WHERE CardNumber = '{numeroCartao}'");
}
```

I don't know what I have to change to work

Comment: How would you expect a single method call to return multiple times? What *single string value* do you expect to be returned?

Comment: @JonSkeet can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @EmanuelSantos: How to solve *what*, specifically?  Take a step back and define what you want this method to return.  Currently it returns a `string`.  *Should it* return a `string`?  A collection of `string` values?  A large `string` in which multiple values are combined?  Something else?

Comment: What you have is essentially the same as [this example code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZwRTf), which only returns the first array element. You've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how methods works and how to return data from methods.

Comment: a collection of string values @David

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code. Most of the code shown in the post is unrelated to the problem - none of the SQL related code is needed (and especially adding SQL injection example distracts from the real problem), `if` inside the `while` should be removed as there is similar code in both branches.  Something like following `while(true) { return "done" }` should be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @gunr2171 i'm still trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618655/my-while-is-only-returning-the-first-result#comment131711531_74618655) you indicate that this method should return:

> a collection of string values

In that case the return type is clearly incorrect:

```
private static string getExtrato(string query)
```

A string is not a collection of string values, in the same way that an apple is not a basket of apples.  Return a collection instead:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> getExtrato(string query)
```

Then in your method you would:

1. Define a collection
2. Aggregate values into that collection
3. Return the collection

Which might look something like this:

```
var result = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read() == true)
{
    if (reader.GetString(1) == null)
    {
        result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " levantou: " + reader.GetString(2) + " euros " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add("\n  O cartão nº " + reader.GetString(0) + " depositou: " + reader.GetString(1) + " euros " + " às: " + reader.GetDateTime(3));
    }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the "if" part you are always returning a value. Let me rewrite the code to clarify your mistake.

```
        while (reader.Read() == true)
        {
                if (condition is met)
                {
                    return "something";
                }
                else //If condition is not met
                {
                    return "something else"
                }
        }
```

Maybe you want to remove the "else" part, but -I have not too much experience using C#- you need to close the connection and other things before return a value.